# For each loop Container - Dynamic Folder

Tags: ssis

I have setup a foreach loop container to go through a set of files in a specific folder. On the dev machine I have set the 'Folder' property to C:\Temp\ however this will be different on the production server. I therefore created a variable, loaded a value from the database for the folder property, assigning it BUT on looping, it's still looking at the C:\Temp folder. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure that the container's lookup folder can be changed dynamically through a variable.

Comment: How do you pass the variable to your loop? Within the expression under Enumerator configuration (Collection --> Foreach Loop Editor --> EExpression)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the directory the foreach is using, proceed as follows:

- open the Foreach Loop Editor
- navigate to "Collection" on the left hand side
- navigate to "Expressions" on the right hand side (directly beneath "Enumerator")
- select "Directory" from the available properties and put your variable as Value